# Find duplicates in environment variables defined in YAML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, yaml, pyyaml

I have a kubernetes deployment YAML file, with defined environment variables including duplicated environment variables.
My goal is detect them and print them, as I have hundreds of files which needs to parsed.

Example YAML:

```
kind: ReplicationController
apiVersion: v1
  spec:
    template:
      spec:
        containers:
          env:
            - name: PROFILE
              value: some_value
            - name: PROFILE
              value: some_value
```

The environment variable key is duplicated with a value, I want to detect it and print the duplicated key.

I tried using PyYAML library in Python but it does not detects at the environment variables level.

Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: PyYAML will help you, but of course you'll need to write additional code to walk the tree it parses to find the duplicated data. After all, the above is perfectly valid YAML...

Comment: We wouldn't expect PyYAML to detect any problems because "my list of dictionaries must be unique on the `name` key" has nothing to do with YAML. You will need to write code that iterates over items in the `env` list, records the names of seen keys, and raises an error if it finds a duplicate.